# Selenium find element next to another one

Tags: selenium

I need to find an element that is located next to another one depending to an if condition. 
For example,  I'm trying to retrieve the bottom with the word “Log In & Pay” only if I found the words ‘DANA’ before. 
I can find the first element with text DANA  in this way, but how can I find then the next botton element with the text “Log In & Pay” ?

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath ("//*[contains(text(), 'DANA')]"));
```

Below the Html page:
[image]

Comment: Use the `following` like 

    `driver.findElement(By.xpath "//*[contains(text(), 'DANA')])//following::div[contains(text()='Log In & Pay')]"`

Comment: Thanks but it is not working.  I'm continuing to try,  changing the parameters

Answer (score 1):

Get the span with the desired text, find the closest ancestor div which contains both els, find the el you want from there. i.e.

```
//span[contains(text(), 'DANA')]
//ancestor::div[@class='web-pay-wallet-inside-wrap']
//div[@class='action']
/div[contains(text()='Log In & Pay')]
```

Answer (score 1):

try using nested predicates

`//div[span[contains(text(), 'DANA')]]/following-sibling::div[@class='action']/div`

Explanation
`//div[span[contains(text(), 'DANA')]]` finds the div which contains span with text DANA
`following-sibling::div` finds the following div at the same level

Answer (score 0):

Selenium 4 introduces relative locators which allow to look up elements in relative position to others. Like:

- above
- below
- right of
- left of
- and even "near"

You can find examples [here](https://webelement.click/en/advanced_techniques_of_element_lookup_in_selenium).